# Python list recursion type error

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree

Solved: It seems that the problem only occurs with PythonWin. I ran everything through the IDLE's python shell and it worked just fine. Must be a bug with PythonWin and not the code itself.

I can't seem to figure out why the following code is giving me a `TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable`

pastebin: http://pastebin.com/VFZYY4v0

```
def genList(self):
    #recursively generates a sorted list of child node values
    numList = []
    if self.leftChild != 'none':
        numList.extend(self.leftChild.genList())  #error
    numList.extend(list((self.Value,)))
    if self.rightChild != 'none':
        numList.extend(self.rightChild.genList()) #error
    return numList
```

code that adds child nodes (works correctly)

```
def addChild(self, child):
    #add a child node. working
    if child.Value < self.Value:
        if self.leftChild == 'none':
            self.leftChild = child
            child.parent = self
        else:
            self.leftChild.addChild(child)
    elif child.Value > self.Value:
        if self.rightChild == 'none':
            self.rightChild = child
            child.parent = self
        else:
            self.rightChild.addChild(child)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Full interpreter session:
>>> import BinTreeNode as BTN
>>> node1 = BTN.BinaryTreeNode(5)
>>> node2 = BTN.BinaryTreeNode(2)
>>> node3 = BTN.BinaryTreeNode(12)
>>> node3 = BTN.BinaryTreeNode(16)
>>> node4 = BTN.BinaryTreeNode(4)
>>> node5 = BTN.BinaryTreeNode(13)
>>> node1.addChild(node2)
>>> node1.addChild(node3)
>>> node1.addChild(node4)
>>> node1.addChild(node5)
>>> node4.genList()
<class 'list'>
>>> node1.genList()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:...\python\BinTreeNode.py", line 47, in genList
    numList.extend(self.leftChild.genList())  #error
  File "C:...\python\BinTreeNode.py", line 52, in genList
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable

Comment: Can you post the whole error?  Or more code.  How are leftChild and rightChild generated?

Comment: @JacobJCallahan: Please update your question with all relevant info.

Comment: here is the full error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\...\python\BinTreeNode.py", line 47, in genList
    numList.extend(self.leftChild.genList())  #error
  File "C:\...\python\BinTreeNode.py", line 52, in genList
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable

Comment: @JacobJCallahan don't post the info in comments, where you can't format it properly.  Edit your question.

Comment: From the code you provided, it seems that `numList.extend()` would always be receiving a list instance. I have a feeling this will only be solvable by seeing all of the code :-/

Comment: @jdi that is the point of this function. basically to return a sorted list form a binary tree. i would call the function from the top node, and it will recursively generate the sorted list.

Comment: `numList.extend(list((self.Value,)))` seems like it should be just `numList.append(self.Value)` ... (that's not your problem, but it would be less confusing) -- You didn't happen to shadow the builtin `list` did you?

Comment: @mgilson that would actually return an int and have a similar error. "TypeError: 'type' int is not iterable"

Comment: @JacobJCallahan: That does not seems right. Something is fishy here.

Comment: I guess post the whole BinTreeNode.py

Comment: @JacobJCallahan -- No, it would return a list with 1 element in it.  As it is, you construct a 1 element tuple, convert it to a list and then use it to extend the list you have.  That's exactly the same thing as appending 1 element to the list you have.

Comment: @jgritty: No that is wrong. That would append a nested list which is not what the OP would want.

Comment: @jdi line 52 is actually just whitespace before the next def on line 53

Comment: @jgritty, that's different than what OP is doing now.  Try it:  `a = []; a.extend(list((1,))); print(a)` gives you `[1]`, not `[[1]]`

Comment: I hate to say it...but even with that interpreter log, it still doesn't make sense. There is nothing in your `genList()` method to indicate that you are returning a type instead of a list instance. Yet your output shows that `genList()` returns a class type.

Comment: @jdi exactly... i can't figure out why it isn't returning the actual list.

Comment: I will test your code if you post a working version.

Comment: added a pastebin link for you

Comment: The sample code seems to work fine for me, Python 2.7.3 on windows.

Comment: Works fine in python 3.3. Are you really running python 3.0?

Comment: correction 3.2.2. I'll try some other stuff tomorrow, thanks

Comment: Worked fine for me on 3.2 as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in your examples to indicate where the problem is coming from, but what it means is that somehow you are returning an object type and not an object instance. All I can offer at this point is to suggest another way to rework the `genList()` method and see if it magically fixes your issue.

You could try passing along the same result list through the recursion, instead of returning lots of temporary ones:

```
def genList(self, numList=None):
    if numList is None:
        numList = []

    if self.leftChild != 'none':
        self.leftChild.genList(numList)

    numList.append(self.Value)

    if self.rightChild != 'none':
        self.rightChild.genList(numList)

    return numList

results = rootNode.genList()
```

Also, is there a reason you are using `'none'` instead of `None` ? I would just use a `None` instead of a string.

My suggested edits to your version are here: http://pastebin.com/FGf8Lcdu

And here is the output of your same interpreter code, under python3.3:

```
In [1]: %cpaste
Pasting code; enter '--' alone on the line to stop or use Ctrl-D.
:>>> import BinTreeNode as BTN
:>>> node1 = BTN.BinaryTreeNode(5)
:>>> node2 = BTN.BinaryTreeNode(2)
:>>> node3 = BTN.BinaryTreeNode(12)
:>>> node3 = BTN.BinaryTreeNode(16)
:>>> node4 = BTN.BinaryTreeNode(4)
:>>> node5 = BTN.BinaryTreeNode(13)
:>>> node1.addChild(node2)
:>>> node1.addChild(node3)
:>>> node1.addChild(node4)
:>>> node1.addChild(node5)
:<EOF>

In [2]: node4.genList()
Out[2]: [4]

In [3]: node1.genList()
Out[3]: [2, 4, 5, 13, 16]
```

Comment: My suggested edits to your pastebin: http://pastebin.com/FGf8Lcdu (Though it works just fine for me in python2.7.3 and python 3.3)

Comment: will do. can you paste your interpreter results? you can use the exact same calls i did.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a couple of prints to see what is the actual type when it gives the error, like:

```
def genList(self):
    #recursively generates a sorted list of child node values
    numList = []
    if self.leftChild != 'none':
        print self.leftChild.genList(), type(self.leftChild.genList())
        numList.extend(self.leftChild.genList())  #error
    numList.extend(list((self.Value,)))
    if self.rightChild != 'none':
        print self.rightChild.genList(), type(self.rightChild.genList())
        numList.extend(self.rightChild.genList()) #error
    return numList
```

A not so wild guess...
Try instead of list((self.Value,)) to use [self.Value].  I have a feeling it will work... :-)

Comment: i ran the commands through the interpreter and got back that they are just returning a list type for some reason here is the result

<class 'list'>

Comment: @JacobJCallahan: was the first printed element the list, or was that the second element?

Comment: @jdi what was printed was the result of running genList() on a node without children. so the problem seems to be that it is returning the type instead of the list itself

Comment: also, the [self.Value] returns the same

Comment: @JacobJCallahan: We need to see more context to know what is wrong here. There is nothing in your current example that indicates where the error would be.

Comment: that is all the context that is relevant. the other code consists of other functions that don't have issues

Comment: If the other code didn't have issues, you wouldn't see this error.  We've established that this line `numList.extend(list((self.Value,)))` is kind of weird, but seems to do the right thing.  Other than that, you're not giving us much to go on.

Comment: @jgritty hope the latest edit helps. this is all i have to go on

Comment: @JacobJCallahan: Unfortunately it does not. Your only choice is to post all your code in a pastebin or something.